# Delete values from list of arrays Python3

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.6

I have a list with 31 elements. Each element is an array with size (586,1383). I would like for each array of this list to remove the zero values, without creating a new list, if this is possible. Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve] and show us the code from your latest attempt.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution:

```
while 0 in ListName:
    ListName.remove(0)
```

Comment: I think what you wanted to say was something like: `for element in list: element.remove(0)`